# Handle Notification Permission Alert buttons clicks

Tags: ios, permissions, push-notification

Can we handle the buttons of notification's permission alert? I have attached an image of this alert. This alerts comes when we install the app for the first time on a device. If the user clicks on "Don't Allow" then the notification feature will be disabled for this app.

So, if the user clicks "Don't Allow", then I want to display a confirmation alert and inform the user that they can enable it from settings again. For this purpose I need to handle notification Alert's button (see the attached image).

If anyone knows the answer to this, please reply.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: By default os will throw you this alert if some settings has not been changed. This will appear only one time when app is opened. You can't create any alert to access the settings page in iPhone. If you do so you app will be rejected 100% for sure

Answer (score 0):

If push notifications were disallowed by user the delegate method :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {  }
```

should be called. This should be the place to show your alert view.

Give it a try!

Cheers